# The potential employer is not responding after the promised date, should I send any letter to them?

Tags: job-search, job-change

I have just passed the job interview. Everything looked good, but I am aware they may have more candidates who are equally good.

The company promised to give me response within a certain time, which has now passed. They they wrote a short message to say that "they need a week more", which has now also passed. If I do not notify my current employer in time, I may end up with the need to negotiate a start date a whole month behind than initially talked about. They know this.

Would it make sense to send a message to the non responding employer of the new job? If so, what should I write in such a message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Optimistically the decision maker is on holiday / ill / too busy.

More likely, they're probably looking for better(1) candidates, hoping to sign one up and stringing you along in case no-one else is suitable. Obviously I don't know if this *is* the case, but if it is, they'll continue looking after hiring you. If you pass probation, you'll spend the next year or so being worried about being replaced.

Forget it and look elsewhere.

---

> If I do not notify my current employer in time, I may end up with the
>   need to negotiate the whole month later employment date than initially
>   talked about. They know this.

I didn't notice that sentence - Don't hand in your notice until you secure something. And look elsewhere.

(1) Better doesn't mean there's anything wrong with you. It might just mean cheaper.

Comment: It does not hurt to ask.  Call the hiring manager (not the HR rep) and ask for a status update.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in sending them a message to ask for news, to ask if the position is still open.

But to me this situation smells not good. Like you said they know everything they need to know about your situation, and if they really were interested in you, they would have accommodate things to make the situation easy for you. But in case they finally call you for the position, they'll know they have to wait.

But in the meantime, don't notice your current employer yet.

Answer (score -1):

Don't hand in your notice with your existing employer **until** the new one has absolutely confirmed your start date, otherwise you could end up with no job..

If they are late organizing, then as you state, they know it costs them a month...